# Why is it ok to remove the observer from a different thread than its original thread in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, observer-pattern, key-value-observing, observers

Why is it ok to remove the observer from a different thread than its original thread in Swift?

I think we may need to dig inside the Swift source code, but I am really curious about this.
Here is a sample code to demonstrate:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var counter = 0
    @objc dynamic var testValue: Bool = false
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] (timer) in
            guard let self = self else {
                print("return")
                return
            }
            self.testValue = !self.testValue
        })

        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "testValue", options: .new, context: nil)

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 7.0, repeats: false, block: { (timer) in
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "testValue")
            }
        })
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "testValue" {
            print("counter : \(counter)")
            counter += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There aren’t any technical issues with removing observer from another thread, but I would advise against it. The biggest concern would be race conditions between the deallocation of the observer and its unregistration from KVO. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1408054-removeobserver) for `removeObserver(_:forKeyPath:)` says:

> Be sure to invoke this method (or `removeObserver(_:forKeyPath:context:)`) before any object specified in `addObserver(_:forKeyPath:options:context:)` is deallocated.

Now in your case, both of your timers happens to be keeping a strong reference to the observer (which itself is a problem; you should be using `[weak self]` pattern in your timers and invalidating them when necessary), but if you fixed that, you’d now introduce a race.

If you add your observers in `init` and remove them in `deinit`, that eliminates any race conditions. (Also if you use [modern KVO syntax](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift), it eliminates this deallocation/unregistration race, too.)

---

Also, remember that `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)` is called on the thread that updated the `testValue` property. So if you’re concerned about threading issues, the thread-safety of both `testValue` and `counter` must be considered, too.

In the absence of any synchronization (e.g., perhaps you’re going to assume that `testValue` will never be updated from a background thread, even though you’re contemplating removing the observer from a background thread), I would suggest making that assumptions inherit to `observeValue` explicit. So, assuming you added your observer like so:

```
addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(testValue), options: .new, context: &observerContext)
```

Then you might add that `dispatchPrecondition` to make the assumption explicit:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    guard context == &observerContext else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        return
    }

    if keyPath == #keyPath(testValue) {
        dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main)) // given that `counter` is not synchronized, let’s warn developer if ever updated `testValue` on background thread
        print("counter: \(counter)")
        counter += 1
    }
}
```

Obviously, you don’t need this precondition if you made `counter` thread-safe through some synchronization.

---

Also, we’d obviously not use KVO to observe a property of the current class (we’d generally just use a Swift observer), but I’m assuming you simplified this for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thank you, it's a thorough answer.
BTW, I think it's ok not using `[weak self]` in the two timers if I mean to keep the viewController working after it's dereferenced from a parent view controller. Although I would normally use `[weak self]` deponded on the purpose of the closure.

Comment: It’s pretty rare that you want to keep a view controller in memory after it has been dismissed. If you have some timer that should survive the dismissal of the view controller, then the timer probably doesn’t belong in the view controller in the first place...

Comment: Yeah... I think you are right. I just try to give some extream cases that might happen in real life projects.